Blue screen appearing on webcam server of raspberry pi.?
Motion version 4.3.2 is used. If i edit the configuration file according to  version 4.1.1 will it work? or is there anyother solution


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
